# The expression "a (la/las) voluntad(es) de otros"

Tags: gramática

> Pero no por ello debemos vivir **a voluntad de otros**, y es una cadena que todos deberíamos empezar a romper.

When using this expression, I'm not sure if "voluntad" should be in the singular or in the plural, as well as if a definite article should be attached to the noun "voluntad".

> vivir a voluntad de otros
>
> vivir a la voluntad de otros
>
> vivir a voluntades de otros
>
> vivir a las voluntades de otros

Answer (score 1):

I'd never use "a voluntad de". The only site where it appears to be used is [this blog](http://laurablanch.com/?s=Pero%20no%20por%20ello%20debemos%20vivir%20a%20voluntad%20de%20otros%2C%20y%20es%20una%20cadena%20que%20todos%20deber%C3%ADamos%20empezar%20a%20romper.).

Normally, we would use a more explicit preposition or phrase with "voluntad":

- vivir **según** la voluntad de los demás
- vivir **de acuerdo con** la voluntad de los demás
- vivir **siguiendo** la voluntad de los demás

(Notice that in the cases above we never use the plural for "voluntad", even if each person's "voluntad" differs from that of others.)

Only when the unit formed by "preposition + noun + de" is a set phrase can we do without the article before the abstract noun within the phrase and before the one that follows, for example:

- **a pedido de** otros
- **por orden de** otros
- **a criterio de** otros

The only case that comes to mind of "voluntad" being used without an article is the phrase "a voluntad":

- Comió **a voluntad**. (He ate as much as he wanted.)

Comment: Hi. Actually, I was under the impression that "a voluntad de otros" might be a set phrase -- therefore the lack of the definite article. If you HAD TO use this expression in this context, which of the four versions that I have listed would you use?

Comment: Hi. I'd use the first one, but you should know it is highly unidiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think your idea would work better if you added "conforme": *vivir conforme a*.

It's pretty common in certain religious contexts to say

> vivir conforme a la voluntad de Dios / Jesucristo / Alá (etc.)

Even though it doesn't appear to be as common to say "vivir conforme a la voluntad de" with some non-religious object of the preposition, I think it works fine.  For example:

> vivir conforme a la voluntad personal

Second, there is an idiomatic way of expressing your idea ("de otros"): **ajena** or **ajena a uno**.  For example

> vivir conforme a la voluntad ajena
>   vivir conforme a la voluntad ajena a uno

If I saw one of these phrases, I would think you were talking about *autonomy* or *self determination* -- which I think is what you are after.